# Connect java application in docker container to rabbitmq

Tags: docker, networking, spring-rabbit

I have a Java application running in a Docker container and `rabbitmq` in another container.

How can I connect the containers to use `rabbitmq` in my Java application?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a network and attach the running containers to the network.

Then you have to set the connection URL of your app to the name of the `rabbitmq`'s network name in Docker container.

The easiest way is to create `docker-compose` file because it will create the network and attach the containers automatically.

[Create a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)

[Connect the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

Or

[Docker compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Example of `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
    version: '3.7'
    services:
      yourapp:
        image: image_from_dockerhub_or_local // or use "build: ./myapp_folder_below_this_where_is_the_Dockerfile" to build container from scratch
        hostname: myapp
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management-alpine
        hostname: rabbitmq
        environment:
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: pass
        ports:
          - 5672:5672
          - 15672:15672
```

You can run it with `docker-compose up` command.

Then in your connection url use `host:rabbitmq`, `port:5672`.

Note that you don't have to create a port forward if you don't want to reach `rabbitmq` from your host machine.